# How I can acess to varibles?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-freezed

I try to use @frezzed tech. in my flutter ptoject for working with  DB-firbase.
[image]

How I can acess to class vars for manipulating?

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
part 'Person.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class Person with _$Person {
  const Person._(); // Added constructor
  const factory Person(String name, {int? age}) = _Person;
  const factory Person.manager(String? ttt) = Manager;
  
  void method() {
    print('hello world');
    Person p = Person("name");
    p.  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@freezed
class Person with _$Person {
  factory Person({ String? name, int? age }) = _Person;
}
```

Which then allows you to write:

```
var person = Person(name: 'Remi', age: 24);
print(person.name); // Remi
print(person.age); // 24
```

source - [freezed docs](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#custom-getters-and-methods)

Comment: Yes. But i have error "The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'Person'.
Try importing the library that defines 'name', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'name'."

Comment: try, refer to this - [article](https://developer.school/how-to-use-freezed-with-flutter/)
freezed implementation - [repo](https://github.com/ThiagoEvoa/dartfn/tree/5c03b19f529ac8ddd0306a4418f6bb99f4213115/dart_backend/lib/model)